# Limitar um "range" usando outro "range"

Tags: jquery, html

Olá, estou desenvolvendo uma página web, e estou precisando limitar um range fazendo uso de outro range.

Eu tenho dois `<input type='range' />` os dois vão de 0 á 10.
preciso que quando um seja alterado para o valor 5 o outro receba um valor total de 5.

Comment: Pode indicar-nos qual é o seu código HTML e qual a relação semântica entre os dois campos? Um *range* irá definir o valor máximo do outro?

Comment: Poderia explicar melhor o que está tentando fazer? O range que você está tentando limitar o que é? É algo de CSS? É algum cálculo com Javascript? É algo com o Java?

Comment: Eu tenho 2 dois "range" os dois vão de 0 á 10, mas preciso que quando um  esteja em 5 o outro fiquei limitado a no máximo 5. Os dois estão em html com a seguinte linha de código:

Comment: <input type="range" min="-60" max="10" value="0" style="width:120px;bottom:-50%;top:60%;height: 5px;  left: -7%" oninput="display.value=value" onchange="display.value=value" list="tickmarks">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bom utilizando seu comentário

> Eu tenho 2 dois "range" os dois vão de 0 á 10, mas preciso que quando
>   um esteja em 5 o outro fiquei limitado a no máximo 5

Desenvolvi uma resposta que utiliza Jquery e satisfaz sua dúvida.

```js
$('.slider1').on('input', function(){
 $('.range1').html($('.slider1').val());
 $('.slider2').attr('max', $('.slider1').val());
});
$('.slider2').on('input', function(){
  $('.range2').html($('.slider2').val());
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h4>Range que define até onde pode ir o outro range</h4>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0.01" id="myTime" class="slider1">
<br>
Valor do primeiro range: <span class='range1'>1</span>
<br>
<h4>O range abaixo tem um valor máximo definido pelo range acima</h4>
<input type="range" min="1" max="10" value="0.01" id="myTime" class="slider2">
<br>
Valor do segundo range: <span class='range2'>1</span>
```

Quando o primeiro range sofre alteração, o segundo range sempre irá receber como valor máximo o valor atual do primeiro range.

Comment: Muito obrigado, ajudou muito...